# Run R code in Sweave .Rnw files in TextMate

Tags: r, latex, textmate, knitr, sweave

I'm editing some .Rnw files in TextMate. The .Rnw files contain R code like this:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua `\Sexpr{mean(mtcars$hp)}`.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat `\Sexpr{mean(mtcars$mpg)}`. Duis aute irure
dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum `\Sexpr{mean(mtcars$wt)}`.

I¹m wondering if its possible to do two things in TextMate, using the R bundle:

1. Place cursor inside a Sweave expression then send the code contained
   within that expression to R app. So if I place the cursor anywhere between \
   and } in any of the three Sweave expressions above, the code within that
   expression would be run in R app. For example, if I place the cursor between
   'h' and 'p', then this would be ran in R app: `mean(mtcars$hp)`
2. Select any text and send any R code within the selected text to R app. So
   if I select the entire text paragraph above, three lines of code would be sent to R
   app: `\Sexpr{mean(mtcars$hp)}`, `\Sexpr{mean(mtcars$mpg)}` and
   `\Sexpr{mean(mtcars$wt)}`